# Where to leave feedback about a bad webhost. Way to combat data loss

Tags: web-hosting

I've been with a certain company (50webs) for a while now. I didn't mind the downtime so much, but a couple of day ago they did the unthinkable:

They went down for a while and I'm guessing restored from a week-old backup without telling any of their customers.

I'm a paid customer and my sites run by storing data in *.dat files in the /www/ directory. As you can imagine I lost a week of data and worst of all an update I finished right before the crash.

I couldn't get in touch with their support staff (form throws errors and phone # disconnected).

That's the background. Now only the question:

I want to leave feedback for the place but have no idea what's a reputable review source these days.

And the less-off-topic question: What's the recommended way of backing up sites like mine that rely on .dat files for data storage? I can think of a bunch of manual ways, but is there something automatic that would for example sync across a couple ftps regularly, or say do a daily dump to google drive?

Thank you guys.

Comment: You're asking two unrelated questions.  You should consider editing this to one specific question about where to go to give and receive feedback about hosting providers and then research backup solutions before asking that part again.

Comment: "...and worst of all an update I finished right before the crash" - Just curious, was this an update to your data (.dat files) or an update to your website/system files? To me, this sounds like the later, but then why wouldn't there be an offline backup of this?

Comment: @w3d No, the former. I uploaded updates THROUGH my site. So when they restored, they literally killed the update with no way for me to get it back except redo the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three sites have the most reviews of the host that I am currently using:

- http://www.000webhost.com/
- http://www.yelp.com/
- http://www.webhostingstuff.com/